# add ListView for every spinner Item..and pops down when clicked

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, jscript

I am beginner on android... I am tried this many times either it shows error or it shows all the listview(array items) from the begining of code running and at a time all together...Here's what need:
I want to add List View inside Spinner Item... For every Spinner Item there will be a list view... Firstly before clicking spinner item it should not show any list view items... And it would show only one list view at a time on selection of spinner item...

[Java[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch0b2.png)

Comment: **ALWAYS** add code to your question as text instead of an image.

Comment: Do you mean that you need expandable listeView ?

Comment: not really...Giving you an example... added a spinner of year... so when select a year(spinner item) ... it will show a list view of movies of that year..

Comment: ok...from next time I will post the code as text..

Comment: expandable list view will work fine... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get this functionality using expandable listview. Refer to [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) tutorial by androidhive for how to create an expandable listview

Comment: @AshikJustice if my answer helped you, please rate it.